# lambda expression path through Collection Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I need to get all `Students` which have `Registration` on specyfic `Realisation`.

I was thinking it would be `s => s.Registrations.RealisationId == realisationId` but it doesn't work :). I'm trying to make this like in the example code but I'm getting:`A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`. I have no idea how can I write this expression correctly, can anyone help me with this?

I couldn't figure out how to title this question better, sorry.

## Database:

```
public class Student : BaseEntity {
    public int StudentId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations {get; set;}
}

public class Registration : BaseEntity {
    public int RegistrationId {get; set;}
    public int StudentId {get; set;}
    public int RealisationId {get; set;}

    public Student Student {get; set;}
    public Realisation Realisation {get; set;}
}

public class Realisation : BaseEntity {
    public int RealisationId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations {get; set;}
}
```

## My try:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetByRealisationId(int realisationId) {
    return Context.Set<Student>().Where(s => {
            foreach(Registration r in s.Registrations) {
                if (r.RealisationId == realisationId)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to select the ID's out and use `Contains`:

```
return Context.Set<Student>()
    .Where(s => s.Registrations
            .Select(r => r.RealisationId)
            .Contains(realisationId));
```

Generally this is converted to a `WHERE IN` clause.

Comment: +1, though I've found that with large tables it can be worth doing a join and then calling `.Distinct()` on the results to avoid `WHERE IN`. Logically they're equivalent, and really the database's optimiser should produce the same lower-level query out of the SQL, but joining is still sometimes better handled than the equivalent `WHERE IN`. I got a shocking improvement changing a `.Contains()` to a join and `.Distinct()` just last week. (Shocking, because one would imagine it would make no difference these days).